# Filter out NULL values while dividing on join

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find the percent difference between the actual and forecast weight of different types of boxes on the same table on an inner join for 4 months. The code works if I were to flop t1 and t2, but I need t1 to be the denominator. However, t1 has some NULL values so the code gets terminated since it divides by zeros in some cases. How do I filter out the NULL values so the table can be created? The Join looks like this:

```
select t1.box_type,
   abs((t1.D1 - t2.D1)/t1.D1)*100 as Diff1,
   abs((t1.D2 - t2.D2)/t1.D2)*100 as Diff2,
   abs((t1.D3 - t2.D3)/t1.D3)*100 as Diff3,
   abs((t1.D4 - t2.D4)/t1.D4)*100 as Diff4
from Boxes t1
  join Boxes t2 on t1.box_type = t2.box_type
where t1.DataCategory IS NOT NULL
  and t1.DataCategory = 'actual' 
  and t2.DataCategory = 'forecast'
```

The IS NOT NULL does not prevent the code from including NULL Values. Can I filter out the NULL values earlier in the code or need to write a new script?

Here is an example of the Data:

```
Data     | Box_Type | D1 | D2   | D3 | D4
Actual        L       8    NULL   9    8
Forecast      L       7    7      8    8
Actual        M       NULL 6      7    7
Forecast      M       5    6      6    7
Actual        S       4    4      3    NULL
Forecast      S       4    3      3    6
```

Comment: You should be checking for NULL in t1.D1, t1.D2, t1.D3 and t1.D4 since those are the columns values in your denominator.  Checking for NULL in DataCategory doesn't do anything, unless the t1 columns are defined as NOT NULL columns.  Some sample data would help with investigating.

Comment: I added an example of what the data looks like

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the NULL values earlier in the code and avoid the "division by zero" error.

Filter out NULL in a CTE and do your SELECT from that CTE.

Answer (score 0):

If you filter out NULL values then you may not able to calculate differences for other columns of that row. Instead you may want to try using CASE expression. Let's assume you want to have 0% as difference if a column of t1 is NULL then your query will look like.

```
select t1.box_type,
   case when t1.D1 is null then 0 else abs((t1.D1 - t2.D1)/t1.D1)*100 end as Diff1,
   case when t1.D2 is null then 0 else abs((t1.D2 - t2.D2)/t1.D2)*100 end as Diff2,
   case when t1.D3 is null then 0 else abs((t1.D3 - t2.D3)/t1.D3)*100 end as Diff3,
   case when t1.D4 is null then 0 else abs((t1.D4 - t2.D4)/t1.D4)*100 end as Diff4
from Boxes t1
  join Boxes t2 on t1.box_type = t2.box_type
where t1.DataCategory IS NOT NULL
  and t1.DataCategory = 'actual' 
  and t2.DataCategory = 'forecast'
```